# Lazarus fails to generate proper InsertSQL, how to remedy?

Tags: sqlite, lazarus, freepascal

I'm using Lazarus and trying to insert payment records into a SQLite database, but apparently InsertSQL isn't autogenerating the correct INSERT statement, and I have discovered that I can't simply assign parameters to .InsertSQL by using .ParamByName like I can to the .SQL property.

My database has tables of **Customers** and **Payments**. The **Payments** table is as follows:

**Pay_Key**: Primary key, Integer, Unique, Not NULL. Identifies a single payment row in the table.
**Pay_Customer**: Integer, Not NULL. Foreign-key linked to an integer-type Not NULL primary key in my Customers table.
**Pay_Sum**: Integer. (Yes, I'm storing the payment sum as integer, but this isn't really important here.)

I'm using **SELECT * FROM Payments WHERE Pay_Customer=:CustomerKey** in my SQLQuery.SQL, and assigning :CustomerKey each time programmatically via SQLQuery.ParamByName('CustomerKey').Text. This lets me navigate existing records nicely in a DBGrid, but when I try to insert a new payment, the operation fails on the "Pay_Customer Not NULL" condition. Apparently Lazarus doesn't know what value to use in the Pay_Customer field, since I passed it programmatically.

Is there a way to remedy this? I can write my own InsertSQL if need be, I just don't understand how I can pass this customer parameter to it. I would very much like to use InsertSQL/UpdateSQL/DeleteSQL, since they would make it easy to use stock DBGrid/DBNavigator components and logic for what I'm doing.

Thanks for any suggestions, and sorry for being so verbose about my question.

-Sam

> Edit: I'm using Lazarus 1.6 (FPC 3.0.0). I have enabled foreign keys in SQLite in SQLite3Connection.Params (foreign_keys=on)